# SwiftUI ScrollView maintain position on new page load

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

In my chat view, each time I load new page (items are added from top), the `ScrollView` jumps to top instead of maintaining `scrollPosition`.

[image]

Here is my scroll view:

```
GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            if viewModel.isLoading {
                LoadingFooter()
            }
            
            messagesView
                .frame(minHeight: geometryProxy.size.height - loadingFooterHeight - bottomContentMargins, alignment: .bottom)
        }
    }
    .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
    .defaultScrollAnchor(.bottom)
    .scrollPosition(id: $scrolledId, anchor: .top)
    .contentMargins(.bottom, bottomContentMargins, for: .scrollContent)
    .onChange(of: scrolledId, scrollViewDidScroll)
}
```

And this is the messages view

```
@ViewBuilder var messagesView: some View {
    LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(sectionedMessages) { section in
            Section(header: sectionHeaderView(title: section.id)) {
                ForEach(section, id: \.id) { message in
                    MessageView(message: message)
                    .padding(.horizontal, .padding16)
                    .padding(.bottom, .padding8)
                    .id(message.id)
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollTargetLayout()
    }
}
```

Printing the `scrolledId` after a page load, I can see it hasn't changed, but the ScrollView position does.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll view does not jump and the position is persisted. It's the old content shifted below the new content!

In the short video you've provided:

- Initially, `ScrollView` is in the top position (lets say `y: 0`) and the `Text("Oct 27")` is in `y: 0`.
- on next load, `Text("Oct 27")` goes below (lets say `y: 500`) and now `Text("Oct 14")` is in `y: 0`!
- After the 2nd load, you are seeing `Oct 13` at `y: 0`.

So you need to move the scroll view on where the old data goes after each load. So it seems like a consistent content size to the user some how.

Here is a pseudo code for this concept:

```
ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in //  Get the proxy
    ScrollView {
        ,,,
        Text("Oct 27")
            .id("Title - Oct 27") //  Give it a proper id
    }
    .onChange(of: messages) { oldValue, newValue in
        if needed {
            scrollProxy.scrollTo("Title - Oct 27") //  Scroll to it after load only if needed
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Note that you may want to have a more accurate position of the content before and after the load. But it will have some more calculations and out of the scope of this question.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure you understood my question. first I use the `scrollPosition` api, so no need for `ScrollViewReader `. the issue is SwiftUI (as UIKit) draws items from the top left corner of the screen, so when adding new items to any view you can expect the items below to be pushed down, I thought `scrollPosition` can handle this but it doesn't. your suggestion might work (set scrolled id after response) but it is a hack and might not cover all cases. like I've mentioned the scrolled id remains with the same value until I start scrolling again.

Comment: How can you achieve the exact same position with the new API? For the code you have posted, it's going to be really glitchy and jumpy.

Comment: @XcodeNOOB, I know, haven't figured it out yet,any suggestions?

Comment: I think the only way is to wrap the scrollView with a wrapper and calculate the offset before adding the data and after it. then to do some math and via a binding with the scrollView wrapper control it and animate to the right value. this way if the user play with the scrollView while you adding content it will work. I'm currently trying to implement it.

Comment: I've already created an observable ScrollView that store content offset and more, PM me if you want an example. still it feels like an hack, there must me a cleaner way to do so, I thought about custom layout, but was facing similar issues because never mind how you layout the views, it still start drawing them from the top left corner.

Comment: Thank you ItayAmza, Send me an email to mohen_z@yahoo.com since there is no PM here, I'll try to clean it a bit a post a gist if I succeed.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem as ItayAmza, and would love to see a solution to this. If someone could post an answer here on Stack Exchange, when resolved, that would be amazing. Thanks guys.